# Divide by zero error sql

Tags: mysql, sql, zero, divide

I get the divide by zero error using this:

```
Select Top 100 *, Case (a.value)
    When 0.0
    Then Null
    Else ((cast(b.value as decimal) - cast(a.value as decimal))/cast(a.value as decimal)) * 100
    End
    as 'Montly Price Change (%)'
From AllProducts a
Join AllProducts b
On a.series_id=b.series_id And (b.Date = DATEADD(month, 1, a.Date))
```

I can't find a way to fix it.. I've tried

```
Select Top 100 *, Case cast((a.value) as decimal)
    When 0.0
    Then Null
    Else ((cast(b.value as decimal) - cast(a.value as decimal))/cast(a.value as decimal)) * 100
    End
    as 'Montly Price Change (%)'
From AllProducts a
Join AllProducts b
On a.series_id=b.series_id And (b.Date = DATEADD(month, 1, a.Date))
```

but this makes my entire column null for some reason..

Comment: Can you supply some values for AllProducts.value, as well as its datatype? Surely seems that the cast or its argument is the only realistic candidate for the source of the error.

Comment: What is the type of `AllProducts.value`? My guess is that it is not matching your `0.0`

Comment: It seems a bit odd that you're testing `a.value` against `0.0` and then casting the same value to a decimal value. Isn't it already a decimal value? Have you tried replacing `cast(a.value as decimal)` with `a.value`?

Comment: The table I'm pulling it from has value set as varchar(30), Values look like this '        0.203'

Answer (score 0):

Any number divided by NULL gives NULL, and no error is generated.

```
Select Top 100 *, Case cast((a.value) as decimal)
        When 0.0
        Then Null
        Else ((cast(b.value as decimal) - cast(a.value as decimal))/NULLIF(cast(a.value as decimal)),0) * 100
        End
        as 'Montly Price Change (%)'
    From AllProducts a
    Join AllProducts b
    On a.series_id=b.series_id And (b.Date = DATEADD(month, 1, a.Date))
```

In case you want to return zero

```
COALESCE(cast(a.value as decimal))/NULLIF(cast(a.value as decimal)),0),0)
```

Comment: I changed to this: 
Select Top 100 *, ((cast(b.value as decimal(4, 4)) - cast(a.value as decimal(4, 4)))/NULLIF(cast(a.value as decimal(4, 4)), 0)) * 100 as 'Montly Price Change (%)'
From AllTheProducts a
Join AllTheProducts b
On a.[Series ID]=b.[Series ID] And (b.Date = DATEADD(month, 1, a.Date)) 

but not it gives me this error: Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

Comment: try to change decimal(4, 4) to larger one

Answer (score 0):

Using NULLIF will work

```
Select Top 100 *,
    ((cast(b.value as decimal) - cast(a.value as decimal))/NULLIF(cast(a.value as decimal),0)) * 100

    as 'Montly Price Change (%)'
From AllProducts a
Join AllProducts b
On a.series_id=b.series_id And (b.Date = DATEADD(month, 1, a.Date))
```

Answer (score 0):

The default scale - the number of places past the decimal point - for the "decimal" type is, I think, 0. As a result, the denominator in your expression for values < 1 is always evaluating to 0. Try using decimal(10,3).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your values are all less than 1?  The default value for the scale of decimal is 0.  So if your values are less than 1, then they will all be converted to 0.  You can define your precision and scale with `cast(a.value as decimal(<precision>,<scale>))`, or you can cast to float.

Something like this should work:

```
Select Top 100 *,
    (cast(b.value as float) - cast(a.value as float))/cast(nullif(a.value,0) as float)) * 100 as 'Montly Price Change (%)'
From AllProducts a
Join AllProducts b
On a.series_id=b.series_id And (b.Date = DATEADD(month, 1, a.Date))
```